# What is the difference between 'it' and 'example' in RSpec?

Tags: rspec

It seems to me that they serve a very similar purpose, I often like to use them to triangulate but fear that there may be some side-effect to doing this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it`, `example`, and `specify` are [synonyms](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/80bdf067758678ee32191c04f4d479031e20606d/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L53-L67). They all do exactly the same thing. The three of them exist to make the tests read like English.